# How do I decode Lotus Notes Dxl <rawitemdata type='502'>? Is this Base64? RFC822 text?

Tags: ruby, lotus-notes, decode

We are importing items exported to dxl from Lotus Notes.  Some items are listed as `rawitemdata type='502'`.  I have found some evidence that these are Mime types, which are Base64 encoded.  Slide 31 of this (http://wenku.baidu.com/view/3d29abcfa1c7aa00b52acb52.html:) indicates they are RFC822 text (researching this)?

```
<item name='PostedDate'>
  <rawitemdata type='502'>
    DgAJAAAACAAEAAIAHgCEPVIAT3MlBERhdGU6IEZyaSwgNyBTZXAgMjAwNyAxMDo1ODoxNyAtMDQwMA==
  </rawitemdata>
</item>
```

When I attempt to decode with Ruby, I get this (note 'Date...' after hex):

```
Base64.decode64('DgAJAAAACAAEAAIAHgCEPVIAT3MlBERhdGU6IEZyaSwgNyBTZXAgMjAwNyAxMDo1ODoxNyAtMDQwMA')
=> "\x0E\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\b\x00\x04\x00\x02\x00\x1E\x00\x84=R\x00Os%\x04Date: Fri, 7 Sep 2007 10:58:17 -040"
```

Any ideas?  I'd prefer an answer with Ruby but would be happy with anything that helps.

Comment: Do you know what data is in the item? I get this � �������„=R�Os%Date: Fri, 7 Sep 2007 10:58:17 -040 when I decode the data. It is TYPE_RFC822_TEXT data. (http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/ShowMyTopicsAllFlatweb/10d98a803c0b621f852570c2006161ce?OpenDocument)

Comment: I do not have the source, just the dxl.  As shown, the rawitemdata is expected to be a PostedDate.  I am confused by the hex characters preceding the date value.

Comment: I can't tell you exactly what's going on in the rawitemdata, but I believe that TYPE_RFC822_TEXT means that there are two stored values.  The data is representing a header from an RFC822 data stream, which must be plain 7-bit text -- that is the "Date:..." portion of what you see.  But the data is also representing the stored binary value of the data.  Since this is the PostedDate field, there is probably going to be TIMEDATE structure in that data -- but that's just 8 bytes and there's a lot more there, and also the byte values look to be too uniformly low to really be a TIMEDATE.

Comment: A way to investigate this would be to take some 'Sent' email messages which are stored in MIME format (so PostedDate will be in RFC822 TEXT format) and export them to DXL.  By comparing the decoded Base64 values for different TIMEDATE values, you can probably figure out what's going on.  Bear in mind that \t in the above string is the same as 0x09, and \b is the same as 0x09.  I.e., it looks like Ruby's string rendering gives you a character if the byte is in the printable range ("=" and "R") a standard escape if it exists (\t and \b), or a hex escape.

Comment: Ooops. I maeant that \b is an 0x08.

Answer (score 0):

PostedDate is a [standard Notes mail field](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21094593) that contains the time/date a message left the sender's mail file. Since everything after "Date:" appears to be a [valid RFC822 date](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z28), I think you can safely Base64 decode and use everything following "Date:" as the value for the PostedDate field, discarding the remaining data.

(I have no idea why DXL rendered the field that way. Maybe [this](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/tools/c/8.5.2/api852ref.nsf/852561bd0045e8e785255b3c005a57bb/a8f1b5243f4d934c482573fb003214eb?OpenDocument&Highlight=0,dxl) is related, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: It was exported that in DXL way because the original message in the NSF file was stored in MIME format.  It was stored that way due to the sender location settings and/or the recipient settings in the Domino Directory.  When a message is stoerd in MIME format, the various date-related header items in the stored note are stored in RFC822 Text format instead of Time/Date format.  You can see this if you examine the document properties of a MIME-formatted message in Notes.

Comment: Makes sense. That's consistent with my local testing with a MIME-rendered rich text field, which produced <rawitemdata type='19'>
AgACAAAAAgBnAAAALwAAAAAAAABDb250ZW50LVR5cGU6IHRleHQvaHRtbDsgY2hhcnNldD0iVVMt
QVNDSUkiDQoNCg0KPGJyPjxmb250IHNpemU9MiBmYWNlPSJzYW5zLXNlcmlmIj4wMS8yNS8yMDEy
PC9mb250Pg0K
</rawitemdata>, which decodes to the same type of hex characters preceding plain text HTML contents.